# Substituting text string in uninitialized table fields having numeric sprintf format

Tags: perl, printf, undefined

I need to format a table row having fields of various numeric data. Some fields have integers and others have real numbers that have to be formatted with a fixed precision. Right justified numbers might be left padded with spaces, others with zeros.

Obviously `sprintf` is the perfect tool for the job.

However, occasionally a table field is undefined, being NULL, n/a and likewise. In such cases I usually have to print a text string like `'NULL'`, `'undef'` or other. (Even leaving it uninitialized makes Perl issue a warning.)

Just plugging in the text string won't do. Beside issuing a warning, a sprintf of say '% 11.2' not only issues a warning "`Argument "NULL" isn't numeric in sprintf at...`" but also prints zero rather than the text string.

Any idea as to how to do what I need?

Comment: It might help to show your code with a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use `printf` with a major format that uses just string fields `%s` together with a set of conditional expressions that return either a number formatted with `sprintf` if the value is defined, or the string `NULL` if it is not

An example should make that clearer

```
my ($f1, $f2, $f3) = ( 700/3, undef, 1/7 );

printf "%11s %11s %11s\n",
    defined $f1 ? sprintf('%.2f', $f1) : 'NULL',
    defined $f2 ? sprintf('%.2f', $f2) : 'NULL',
    defined $f3 ? sprintf('%.2f', $f3) : 'NULL';
```

#### output

```
 233.33        NULL        0.14
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the `"%s"` format instead and a helper sub routine: For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $num = "N/A";

printf "%s\n", format_float( $num );

sub format_float {
    return ($_[0] eq "N/A") ? $_[0] : sprintf "%f", $_[0];
}
```

Comment: OK Hakon, this would probably work. But you see, I don't just output a formatted string. Both the number, if defined, and the substitute string for undef must be of the same length to fit nicely in a table with the same-width columns. i.e., '% 11.2f' must be translated into '% 11s'. But I think Borodin showed below how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can be 99% certain that all non-number "values" you need to deal with will *not* have a digit anywhere, this is probably what you want:

```
sprintf (($num =~ /\d/) ? "%11.2f" : "%s", $num)
```

If you need to additionally distinguish integral from float numbers, you'll have to do more...

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Yes, and Borodin even extended it below. That's how I need it.

Comment: OK. The answers are quite different actually. I thought you were getting literal strings like "NULL" and "n/a" in your data that you wanted to "pass thru". But if you are getting undef Perl variables in all non-numeric cases, then Borodin's is the right way.